# Disable selected option in f:form.select

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I want to use `<f:form.select>` to display list of address type. But i want too disable some of options. How can i disable it? Effect should be like:

[image: selectbox with one option disabled]

My current code is like (fully working, but without disabled options):

```
<f:form.select class="form-control"
    property="type"
    options="{addressType}"
    optionLabelField="title"
    prependOptionValue="0"
    prependOptionLabel="Please select"/>
```

i tried read documentation and check google but nothing is here. I can do it with `<option value="any" disabled>` but this is not solution because i use `<f:form action(...)>` and i use object with this

What can i do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `f:form.select.option` inside a loop inside `f:form.select` to render your options manually, then use `additionalAttributes` to add the `disabled="disabled"` attribute. Be aware that passing `additionalAttributes="{disabled: valueMaybeNull}"` could render the attribute anyway, which means you'd need a condition around the entire `f:form.select.option` to render one way when disabled and another when active.

See https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/typo3/cms-fluid/8.7.17/Form/Select/Option.html

Comment: looks cool, i check this. Thanks, i didn't found this because i worked on typo3.7 but anyway, we soon update our typo to v.8 and i can use you solution.